# How do I reuse a name after returning it with a function?

Tags: python, function

I'm taking a basic computer programming class and stumbled across an issue where I don't know how to use a variable from a previous function. The prompt is to take a starting value and ending value and calculate the numbers in between. How can I change this?

I haven't really tried anything. I'm really stuck.

```
def getStartNum():
    startValue = int(input("Enter starting number: "))
    while(startValue<0):
        print("Invalid input.")
        startValue = int(input("Enter starting number: "))
    return startValue
def getStopNum():
    stop = int(input("Enter the ending number: "))
    while(stop <= startValue):
        print("Ending number must be greater than the starting value.")
        stop = int(input("Enter the ending number: "))
    return stop
def sumOfNums(startValue, stop):
    total = 0
    for i in range(startValue, stop+1, 1):
        total+=i
    return total
def productOfNums(startValue, stop):
    product = 1
    for j in range(startValue, stop+1, 1):
        product*=i
    return product
st = getStartNum()
sp = getStopNum()
ns = sumOfNums(st, sp)
p = productOfNums(st, sp)
print("The sum of the sequence is:", ns)
print("The product of the sequence is:", p)
cont = input("Do you want to continue? y/n: ")
```

The error message:

```
    while(stop <= startValue):
NameError: name 'startValue' is not defined
```

I expected the output to print the sum and products immediately

Comment: You can't - that's why it's called a *local* variable.

Comment: The `getStopNum()` function doesn't know about `startValue`.  You should probably pass it in as an argument.

Comment: `startValue` is not a variable in the `getStopNum()` function, it is only ever a local name in the `getStartNum()` function. You'll have to pass it in as an argument to the `getStopNum()` function, or use `st`, the global name to which you assigned the return value of `getStartNum()`

Comment: Programming languages have local variable names to make it easier to re-use names in functions without having to worry about clashing with the same name being used in a different way in a different function. If all names were global, you would have to be far more creative with naming.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use variables that were initialised in other functions outside of those functions (it's called 'scope'). You'll have to pass the start value in as an argument just as you did with `sumOfNums(startValue, stop)`

```py
def getStopNum(startValue):
    stop = int(input("Enter the ending number: "))
    while(stop <= startValue):
        print("Ending number must be greater than the starting value.")
        stop = int(input("Enter the ending number: "))
    return stop
st = getStartNum()
sp = getStopNum(st)
```

And do so for all your functions that need the value.

also you can read more about this thing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45638126/difference-between-local-variable-and-global-variable)